# Get cell range for a function argument from the text of another cell in libreoffice-calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Consider some libreoffice-calc function called `MYFUNC` which takes a cell range for example `A2:B40` as an argument, so I can call `MYFUNC(A2:B40)`.

Now I want to be able to write `A2:B40` as text into another cell say `D4` and give the cell range defined in `D4` as an argument to `MYFUNC`. I.e. I want to be able to write something like this `MYFUNC(GETCELLRANGEFROM(D4)` which should be equivalent to `MYFUNC(A2:B40)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `GETCELLRANGEFROM(D4)` by `INDIRECT(D4)` should do what you want to achieve (given that D4 contains the string `A2:B40`). The [INDIRECT](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_INDIRECT_function) function "translates" a string into a reference.

Here's a short example how it works:

[image]

- A1 to A9 holds some numbers,
- B1 has a `string` value, representating a reference to column A;
- C1 has the formula `=SUM(INDIRECT(B1))`

So, C1 calculates a sum, based on the reference string in B1. Modifying B1 to `A1:A7` will change C1, too (resulting in 28). This way, INDIRECT "translates" a string to a reference that can be used in another (surrounding) formula.