# How to reference variable sheet in OpenOffice Calc?

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice-calc

I want to reference a cell in another sheet, and the formula I get when pressing `=` followed by changing sheet, clicking on the cell and pressing Enter, gives me

```
'Sheet2'.A2
```

Which is fine, except that cell B3 in Sheet1 contains the name of the sheet to select from.

So how can I avoid hard coding the name of the sheet and instead use the value of a cell as the sheet name?

I've googled and looked up OOo documentation and wikis, but to no avail.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/371970/get-cell-range-for-a-function-argument-from-the-text-of-another-cell-in-libreoff

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related in the use of `INDIRECT` for the solution. But this question is specific to referencing another sheet, for which special syntax seems to be needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is called an [Indirect Reference](http://www.openofficetips.com/blog/archives/2005/03/advanced_functi.html).

```
INDIRECT(B3&".A2")
```

I believe would do what you're looking for.

To explain, it's the concatenation of the string value of cell `B3` in the current sheet and the string `".A2"`. The resulting string, `"Sheet2.A2"`, is then evaluated as a reference.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed! Here's the formula that worked in the end for my example: `INDIRECT(B3&".A2")` - where B3 is the cell in the current sheet that contains the name of the sheet to look for A2, which has the value I'm looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I just edited the answer first so other people don't have to look in the comments for the solution :-)

Comment: Be careful, In some Libre Office versions the formula might a bit difference. For example the following formula works in mine.
INDIRECT(B3&"!A2") instead of INDIRECT(B3&".A2")